# startActivity and startActivityForResult with the same Activity?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and I have a `ListActivity`.

Sometimes, I need to open it with `startActivityForResult` and sometimes with `startActivity`.

I think I can do it, but I'm not sure. I have two questions:

1. **Can I start the same activity forResult and normally?**
2. **How con I know on `ListActivity` that it was started with `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`?**

Comment: ref for more info on this: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-task-and-back-stack-review-5017f2c18196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I start the same activity forResult and normally?

***Yes you can.***

> How con I know on ListActivity that it was started with startActivity
>   or startActivityForResult?

*See [getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) for more details.*

So you can check in Activity before finishing for calling activity. If result is null Activity was called by  `startActivity()` and if result is not null then Activity was called by `startActivityForResult()`. Thats it.

example :-

```
if (getCallingActivity() == null) {
    //This Activity was called by startActivity 
} else {
   //This Activity was called by startActivityForResult
}
```